# What's the meaning of 'would'?

Tags: modal-verbs

> I didn’t look [at Mrs. Dubose lying on the bed] any more than I had
>   to. Jem repened Ivanhoe and began reading. I tried to keep up with
>   him, but he read too fast. When Jem came to a word he didn’t know, he
>   skipped it, but Mrs. Dubose **would** catch him and make him spell it
>   out.  . . . 
> From time to time she **would** open her mouth wide
>   and I could see her tongue undulate faintly. (Harper Lee, To Kill A
>   Mockingbird)

(1) I guess ‘would’s in the example pertain to ‘used to express repeated or habitual action in the past' ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/would?s=t)). Is this right? (2) If yes, I’m still wondering if ‘would’ be used for the meaning, when a event is repeated in a day at the same place, as the example. (3) If both are right, can I say ‘Mrs. Dubose repeatedly caught him’ instead of the original text?

Comment: I don't think it *would* reasonable to use "repeatedly" there, because it would significantly change the emphasis. As it stands, the total number of times Mrs Dubose "caught him out" might actually be quite small. The important thing isn't that she did this *very often* - it's that ***if** he skipped a word, she **would** catch him* (even if this didn't happen very often). In the context of a narrative such as this, there's a thin line dividing *being **predisposed** to doing something, should the situation arise*, and ***actually** doing something often (because the situation arises often)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, why i'm asking this is this event happened in a daytime, not for a certain period of days. That's why i made two questions.

Comment: @ Listenever: I understand what you're getting at, but you're only seeing a difference between the two contexts because you're interpreting *would* too rigidly as *repeatedly*. In this type of writing style, the author is really just trying to convey the essence of what Mrs Dubose was like (by giving *examples* of what she would do in various situations). He doesn't really want to emphasise the idea that she *repeatedly* did any of the things he describes (including maybe some she rarely or never actually did, but she would do things *like* that).

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but *would* is the past tense of *will*.  If you and I are talking about Mrs Dubose in the present and you're going over to read to her, I might say, "When you are reading a book to Mrs. Dubose and you come to a word you don't know, she *will* make you stop and spell it out. And sometimes she will open her mouth wide so you can see her tongue."  And now let's think about you and I getting together to reminisce about when we used to read to her.  Now we can say, "Remember when you'd come to a word you didn't know and she *would* make you spell it out?"

Comment: @Jim: Even if it doesn't help OP, I think that's a nice clear way of putting things. So even though I can't link directly to your comment, I've flagged it up in [my answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5678/126) to the question I think this one duplicates.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You *can* [link directly to his comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/whats-the-meaning-of-would#comment8431_5674); get the URL by clicking on the timestamp.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't get hung up on the idea of "on the same day". Past tense means simply that something happened in the past. Depending on the context this could mean yesterday, a thousand years ago, or two seconds ago. To quote the definition you cite, I might describe something as "habitual action" if I observed someone to do this every day for years. "He had a habit of getting up early." But I might also describe something as "habitual action" if someone did it twenty times in the first half hour after I met him. "He had a habit of scratching his ear."