# What are the meanings of 'would's in the example?

Tags: modal-verbs

> “Jeremy Finch, I told you you’d live to regret tearing my camellias.
>   You regret it now, don’t you?”
>  Jem **would** say he certainly
>   did.
>  “Thought you could kill my Snow-on-the-Mountain, did you?
>   Well, Jessie says the top’s growing back out. Next time you’ll know
>   how to do it right, won’t you? You’ll pull it up by the roots, won’t
>   you?”
>  Jem **would** say he certainly would.
>  “Don’t you
>   mutter at me, boy! You hold up your head and say yes ma’am. Don’t
>   guess you feel like holding it up, though, with your father what he
>   is.”
>  Jem’s chin **would** come up, and he **would** gaze at Mrs.
>   Dubose with a face devoid of resentment. Through the weeks he had
>   cultivated an expression of polite and detached interest, which he
>   would present to her in answer to her most blood-curding inventions.
>   (Harper Lee, To Kill A Mockingbird)

What’s the meaning of ‘would’s in the example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have easy access to the full text, and I certainly don't recall this exact section of the book, but I've no doubt this is an example of *would* in its [habitual aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_aspect).

That's to say, *would = used to = was in the habit of*. It's often used in narrative contexts such as OP's, but it can be slightly confusing when reported speech is involved.

In order to add "immediacy" to his text, the writer uses reported speech. Logically it's inconceivable Mrs Dubose would be in the habit of using those exact words repeatedly, but it would be distracting if the writer preceded her every utterance with *Mrs Dubose would say something like*. In fact, Harper Lee quite wisely doesn't even bother explicitly pointing out that it's Mrs Dubose speaking in the first place; the reader is expected to realise this without being told.

It may also be helpful to note [@Jim's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5674/whats-the-meaning-of-would#comment8431_5674) to [a closely-related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5674/126), which explains very clearly the implications of the fact that ***would*** is the past tense of **will**.

---

TL;DR: Mrs Dubose would say (was in the habit of saying) things similar to those reported. Jem habitually agreed to all her (somewhat rhetorical) questions.

Comment: I think this "would" is not habit but just "said." the past...in this case, this "would" is not very different from the simple past. It feels different from "I would go fishing with my dad." What do you think?

Comment: @username901345: Don't interpret "habitual aspect" too literally. All instances of past tense ***would*** in OP's excerpt are indeed "habitual aspect", in that *often/more than once* Jem did each of the things specified (or something very similar, it needn't be 100% accurate in such contexts). If simple past were used, that would describe ***single instances*** of the actions having occurred - each of which might have been a very unusual thing for Jem to have done (but in fact they're *typical* of the kind of things he used to do).

Comment: So if one's past action. even if just a one time action like "say", is something that can be imagined from his personality or behavior, then would can be used ?

Comment: @username901345: There's some "overlap" in the usages, but note that if I say *"StoneyB would agree with me on this point"*, that's really "present/future" *irrealis* mode (**if** he reads this now or in the future then he will agree). If we were talking about a "single past action" (that could have, but probably didn't happen) it would be *"StoneyB **would have agreed** with me on this point"* (if he *had* read it, which in fact he didn't).