# What does this mean grammatically?

Tags: modal-verbs

There was no one who would not talk ill of him.

What does this "would" mean grammatically?

Comment: What was the original sentence?

Comment: There were none who knew Messer Antonio da Venafro as the servant of Pandolfo Petrucci, Prince of Siena, who would not consider Pandolfo to be a very clever man in having Venafro for his servant.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means the writer isn't a native speaker of English. The "double negative" phrasing is clumsy, but might be excused if it weren't for the "misuse" of the verb ***to talk***. Usage figures from Google Books...

> *["talk ill of him"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20was%20always%20meant%20for%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22talk%20ill%20of%20him%22&tbm=bks)* - 2890 results
>    *["speak ill of him"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20was%20always%20meant%20for%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22speak%20ill%20of%20him%22&tbm=bks)* - 103,000 results

In fact it's much worse than even those figures would suggest - the vast majority of those 2890 results are from non-native speakers, deliberately archaic-sounding texts, or were written over a century ago.

As to the semantic content, if we "cancel out" the negatives ***no-one*** and ***not*** speak ill, we end up with...

> *"Everyone spoke badly of him"* (i.e. - everyone would say bad things about him)

It can either mean *that's what they **would** say (if asked their opinion)*, or *that's what they **habitually** said (not necessarily only when asked)*. There's no way to say for sure, but it makes no real difference here. See [this previous answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5678/126) for more on *would do = habitually did*.

Comment: Another (more natural-sounding) phrasing: _No one had anything good to say about him_. It's not an precise match in meaning, but you still get the idea that he's a scoundral.

Comment: @J.R.: Yes, that's another good alternative. And even if those of us with an ear for Victorian phrasing can "just about" tolerate OP's ***talk ill of him***, I don't suppose *anyone* would be willing to accept *"No one had anything good to **talk** about him."*

Answer (score 0):

"Would" here means "was willing to" or "was likely to."

So, rephrased, your sentence is equivalent to either/both of the following:

> There was no one who was not willing to talk ill of him.
>
> There was no one who was not likely to talk ill of him.

For clarification, let me add a name:

> There was no one who was not likely to talk ill of John.

Therefore, if you ask anybody what he or she thinks about John, you will receive a bad opinion about John.